# Bug with oracle using propel 1.3

Tags: oracle, timestamp, propel

I have a problem on a symfony 1.1 project with propel 1.3. I'm using the sfGuardPlugin.  This plugin bug because of oracle timestamp. Something like "12/12/08 18:16:02,00000000000".

I'm using propel 1.3, so i'm using PDO. But it gives me oracle timestamp strings "AS IS". How can i force propel to convert these strings for me ?

Propel should be giving something like propel.defaultTimeStampFormat = Y-m-d H:i:s

That's not the first propel 1.3 bug i got with oracle. My job is to migrate a symphony project from 1.0 to 1.1 (currently) then from 1.1 to 1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Propel 1.6, it's a bit different than 1.3 even if to pass from 1.4 to 1.6 is safe as backward compatible has been kept. A lot of fixes have been made for Oracle since 1.3.

BTW you can use Propel 1.6 with the sfPropelORMPlugin for Symfony 1.3/1.4.

Unfortunately, you won't get any help for Propel 1.3 if there is a bug on the Oracle adapter as this version is really old.

Comment: Thanks. I know that propel 1.4 is working with my office oracle server  on symfony 1.4. I will try to make it work with symfony 1.1.